# Replace fields smaller than 1, then filter rows with values greater than 1

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have been trying to filtering some csv files that I have for a long time. Almost doing it by hand since I can't figure out why my scripts are not working. Hope you guys can figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have the following file: [csv file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62277598/genes.csv)

I am able to replace the values that are smaller than 1 using the following sed script:

```
sed -e 's/[0][0-9]*\.[0-9]*/0/g'  genes.csv > genes-filtered1.csv
```

In the next step I would like to remove all rows that have all zeros. However I want to keep then if they have a value greater than 1 in at least one column. I tried several scripts but it does not work.

Here are some of them:

```
awk '{ if ($2 > 1 || $3 > 1 || $4 > 1 || $5 > 1 || $6 > 1 || $7 > 1 || $8 > 1 || $9 > 1 || $10 > 1 || $11 > 1 || $12 > 1 || $13 > 1) print $0 }' genes-filtered1.csv > genes-filtered2.csv
```

or just trying to filter by one column using threshold:

```
threshold=1
awk -v threshold=$threshold '$3 > threshold' genes-filtered1.csv > genes-filtered2.csv
```

I also tried:

```
awk '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i != 0) { print; next } } }' genes-filtered1.csv > genes-filtered2.csv
```

Finally I tried:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>=1){print $0;next}}' genes-filtered1.csv > genes-filtered2.csv
```

The problem is that the output file is either empty or the same as the original. Any suggestion how to fix it will be appreciated. Also would it be possible to have an awk command to do what I am doing with sed and then remove the lines with all zeros? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR > 1 {
    allZeros = 1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i < 1) {
            $i = 0
        }
        else {
            allZeros = 0
        }
    }
}
!allZeros
' file
```

Comment: Thank you. Initially it did not work. However the problem was within my files. After doing what @jaypal said below (use dos2unix) it works. Thank you.

Comment: @degopwn You should use and accept this solution. I haven't tested but I'm sure it is more efficient since it only iterate the lines once giving some performance boost.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `awk`, you don't really need to use `sed`. The following solution will enable a flag `f` when any one field is greater than `1`. If the flag is true then we will iterate through fields again and convert all values less than `1` to `0`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }         # Set input and output field separator to ,
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
        if ($i >= 1) { f = 1 }   # Enable a flag when any one field is greater than 1
}
f {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { 
        $i = ($i < 1 ? 0 : $i)   # If the flag is true convert values < 1 to 0
    }
    f = 0;                       # Set the flag to false
    print                        # Print the line
}' file
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I need first to convert the values smaller than 1 to zero (it is a threshold for a gene to be considered expressed). Then I need to check across all samples (columns) to make sure the gene is expressed in at least one sample. Then I use it to plot a Trellis graph with Lattice. Somehow with your suggestion the it works but the change the format of the file. It print the first two rows and then put all the other rows in front of it. Best.

Comment: @degopwn Looks like your file has control characters. Can you run your file through `cat -vet filename` and see if you find any `^M` characters. If so then you probably need to do `dos2unix` on your file to convert the windows line endings to unix line endings

Comment: Yes, it had lots of it. Now it is working. Thanks a lot.